# set PHP path from host to docker container

Tags: php, docker, environment-variables, visual-studio-code

i know this is rather a stupid question, but i have the following problem. i use Docker above a year and a editor to change my programm which is hostet as a volume.

i dont have installed php because it only runs inside of the containers, like almost all other of my server programms (like sql, apache). now i installed visual studio code and it cannot find the path to php to use intellisense.

i know that i can set an environment path inside my docker-compose or Dockerfile to set an environment for my container. but the container is, if its run, isolated to the outside, except for commands like docker cp.

is it possible to set a path from my host machine to the container machine, so that visual studio code can find PHP inside of the container and use it for intellisense? or do i have to install php on my host machine? but this would destroy the usage of the Docker containers in my opinion.

for example in visual studio code config `settings.json`

```
"php.validate.executablePath": DOCKERCONTAINER/usr/bin/php
```

Comment: Lets say you have your php dir exposed in your container, it has all the executables etc in it. If you then map it to a local folder the contents of _that_ folder then overwrite what is in the container. If there is nothing in that folder then your containers directory will now have nothing in it. The way volumes work doesn't allow for mapping files from the container back to the host, it's a one way deal.

Answer (score 26):

The trick is to create a Bash file that calls to our PHP container.

At first, start a PHP7 container and keep it running by using this docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:  
  python:
    image: php:7.2
    container_name: php7-vscode
    restart: always #this option will keep your container always running, auto start after turn on your host machine
    stdin_open: true
    networks:
      - proxy
networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
```

Create a file named php in /usr/local/bin

Chmod to make it executable

```
sudo chmod +x php
```

This file will contain this script that use our running container to process php

```
#!/bin/bash
docker exec -i --user=1000:1000 php7-vscode php "$@"
```

1000:1000 is our user id and our user group on our host machine. We have to run as our current user on host machine so that the container won't modify our file's owner.

That's it. Now you can type

```
php -v
```

to see the result.

Comment: thanks man, for the people who are on windows this is your solution `docker exec -i php7-vscode php %*` puth it in a php.bat file.

Comment: BUT now i see the composer cant run, how can fix that?

Comment: @mohammadfallah.rasoulnejad mine still works. you need to create the network proxy in order to run my docker-compose. If you don't want to create it, you can remove the network proxy.

Comment: can you explain a little bit? were can i set that proxy? on windows network settings? or on `docker-compose.yml` file? bc i have a network set up for my containers if you mean that network?

Comment: I think you can simplify it

`php
version: "3"
services:  
  python:
    image: php:7.2
    container_name: php7-vscode
    stdin_open: true
`

Comment: I..I cant understand, im actually new to docker can you please answer me here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59375780/docker-php-container-and-local-composer-issue i posted a question. thanks in advance

Comment: Oh, so you're using it on Windows. In my tutorial, I mentioned this step `Create a file named php in /usr/local/bin`. This one only apply on Linux.

Comment: yes im on windows and i could somehow do that with a php.bat file so i can add this file to environment variables and whenever i call something like php -v on command prompt, i get results from the container. thats ok but for some reason its not working with composer. thats really frustrating.

Comment: i think i should install composer on the php container and use another composer.bat file in windows? i think that would be a solution but isnt there another way available?

Comment: oh, i just tried it and it works! thanks anyway. your answer to this question was inspired me to solve my problem after all.