# VisualStudio Code PHP executablePath in docker

Tags: php, docker, visual-studio-code

I try to configure VSCode to use our php executable inside a docker container. Firstly i tried it on a macintosh and everything works as expected. At work we use windows pc´s and i cant get it to work.

**Workspace Settings**

```
"php.suggest.basic": false,
"php.executablePath": "C:\\Source\\stack\\.bin\\php.bat",
"php.validate.executablePath": "C:\\Source\\stack\\.bin\\php.bat",
"php.validate.run": "onSave",
"php.validate.enable": true
```

I tried to set a `.sh`, `.exe` or `.bat` file but none of them seemed to work.

**php.bat**

```
@echo off
docker run -i stack_php php %*
```

**php.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
docker run stack_php php "$@"
return $?
```

Anybody of you can help me get this to work? We would like to change our IDE from PHPStorm to VSCode but we arent able to so because everything a developer needs is stored in docker containers.

Answer (score 26):

I came up with a solution on Linux for multiple laravel sail projects.

Create a file named 'php' on /usr/local/bin

```
sudo touch /usr/local/bin/php
```

Make it executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/php
```

Edit the file (with sudo) and paste this code:

```
path=$(printf '%s\n' "${PWD##*/}")
command="docker exec ${path}_laravel.test_1 php "$@""
echo "Running php on docker ${path}_laravel.test_1"
$command
```

Now just run, example,  'php -v' inside the laravel sail project.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Now I can use some php extensions with vscode running on WSL.

Comment: Why `${path}_laravel.test_1` Should I change it for anything else?

Comment: Nice idea :-) I moved it into my local bin, that also worked

Comment: I can't believe there's no built-in support for this and one has to reach out to such tricks. Still, thank you for sharing this :)

Comment: This is a nice solution! Wouldn't be better to keep the "executable" in the project folder, so it's tied to the project container? By doing that every project would have it's own container + config

Comment: FYI, I had to change `${path}_laravel.test_1`  to `${path}-laravel.test-1`  (the underscores to hyphens) for this solution to work.

Answer (score 11):

Or you can use plugin for that: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=henriiik.docker-linter

Example how to configure it correctly could be found in their repository https://github.com/henriiik/vscode-docker-linter/blob/master/playground-php/.vscode/settings.json

You will need to modify the existing settings to look like this example below...

```
{
    "php.validate.enable": false,
    "docker-linter.php.enable": true,
    "docker-linter.php.container": "stack_php",
    "docker-linter.php.machine": ""
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are running Docker on Windows and WSL2 you should replace the underscores for dash like this:

```
path=$(printf '%s\n' "${PWD##*/}")
command="docker exec ${path}-laravel.test-1 php "$@""
echo "Running php on docker ${path}-laravel.test-1"
$command
```

It took me a while to find out, i hope this can help someone.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue, and just found a solution, but in my case I'm working under the Windows Subsystem for Linux, not straight Windows, so I'm not sure if/how it would be adapted. You can read more about it here: [set PHP path from host to docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44501237/set-php-path-from-host-to-docker-container)

For me, the part that seemed to resolve the problem was moving the "wrapper" to `/usr/local/bin`, and then setting that as my php.validate.executablePath for the Workspace (you could also set it at the Remote WSL level, but in my case, I might develop with multiple versions of PHP)

I hope that might help you!

Update:
I just saw someone in the comments was working in Windows!
They suggested putting

```
docker exec -i your_container_name php %*
```

into a .bat file; looking at what you've already done, the difference appears to be using `exec` instead of `run`

Comment: can you please provide your solution in details as I am with same scenario as yours with Windows, WSL2 and Docker. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My solution using [Laradock](http://laradock.io/) on Linux Mint.

Create a file named 'php' on /usr/local/bin

```
sudo touch /usr/local/bin/php
```

Make it executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/php
```

Edit the file (with sudo) and paste this code:

```
command="docker exec -i laradock_workspace_1 php "$@""
$command
```

If you don't use Laradock, change `laradock_workspace_1` to your container name.

VsCode settings.json

```
"php.validate.executablePath": "/usr/local/bin/php",
"php.executablePath": "/user/local/bin/php",
```

Credits:

- Sterferson
- Malcalevak

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft now has an extension that allows you to open a vscode project inside a container context. This lets you use the PHP executable loaded inside a Docker container for intellisense and other features.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-remote-release#readme