# How to set PHP path in VSCode using WSL-Remote ddev container?

Tags: ddev

I'm using ddev in WSL2 & trying to use https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shevaua.phpcs that asks for `php.validate.executablePath`.

I don't want to install PHP locally on WSL as that won't be a packaged solution. I hope there's a way to access PHP from my local ddev's docker container.

This answer resolves the issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/66376387, but I'm unable to understand the `laravel` thing there & my goal is to make it ddev generic so that I can use it in multiple projects.

Comment: You may want to use vscode remote, https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers, which would solve this issue.  (You'd be working inside the container, so everything would be fine).

But creating a dummy php script that just does a `ddev php` would work for you, as in the linked answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you, @rfay, for providing such a valuable tip. This is how I followed your instructions:

- Created a file named 'php' at `/usr/local/bin` using `sudo touch /usr/local/bin/php`
- Made it executable: `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/php`
- Edited the file (with sudo) using `sudo vim /usr/local/bin/php`
- Added the following code:

```
path=$(printf '%s\n' "${PWD##*/}")
command="ddev php "$@""
$command
```

I did all the above operations to the WSL2 Ubuntu container.

Comment: Hi, I had the same problem as you and I followed the instructions you gave above.
But VS Code gives an error: 
Command failed with exit code 255: /usr/local/bin/php --version ERror: unknown command
"php" for "ddev" Run 'ddev --help' for usage

Can you explain the code you put above so I can know if I did something wrong? thanks

Comment: @Rastographics I think the reason of the error is that you opened a PHP file outside of a DDEV project. That's the error I receive when I tried to do the same. However, when I run `ddev php` in a ddev project folder, the command succeeds

Comment: I also want to add, that it can be stored/generated at project level.
I put the script into a `.ddev/php/php` and added configuration to `php.validate.executablePath` like this:
`${workspaceFolder}/.dev/php/php`
Works like a charm.
I wish it will may be generated based on some ddev config value.

Comment: This fails for me, either as described in the answer or in @voleger's comment. I get `phpcs: Unable to locate phpcs. Command failed: "/home/nick/projects/my_project/vendor/bin/phpcs" --version [31mFailed to run php /home/nick/projects/my_project/vendor/bin/phpcs --version: exit status 1[0m`. I do have `/home/nick/projects/my_project/vendor/bin/phpcs`. It also fails with the 'PHP Sniffer & Beautifier' extension. PHPStan via the 'phpstan' extension fails too. I need to install PHP in Ubuntu (in WSL2) for these to work.