# ddev and vscode for Drupal, what should I use for php.validate.executablePath?

Tags: visual-studio-code, drupal, ddev

I installed ddev on macOs Sonoma. I installed Drupal via ddev in folder /Users/darkokan/sites/review-dev-d10
I can start Drupal with:

> ddev launch

command and it works fine.
When I open vscode I get an error saying that I need to set variable
"php.validate.executablePath": ""
in ~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json
I need to set it to PHP which runs from the container. (I don't have PHP installed on mack) I can run container PHP in the command line, when I go to folder /Users/darkokan/sites/review-dev-d10 and run
ddev exec php -v I get the correct response.
What would be the value for my php.validate.executablePath.
I read that I need to create a wrapper file in /usr/local/bin/php and make it executable:
[VisualStudio Code PHP executablePath in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53501925/visualstudio-code-php-executablepath-in-docker).
What would I put in that file given I have zshel and Drupal in containers?

Comment: I don't know vscode very well, but you can certainly install PHP with `brew install php` and tell vscode to use that binary.

Comment: With `brew install php` you are able to install PHP on the host, that definitely works. But the version inside the container might differ from the one installed on the host. The more ideal case would be being able to use the PHP binary used in the projects container. There is the VSCode remote extension I never managed to get working and it is also sort of slow (it copies a copy of VSCode into the container if i remember correctly). The cleaner solution might be if the following idea would be implemented in the vscode-ddev-manager https://github.com/ddev/vscode-ddev-manager/issues/11

Comment: thanks, both to answer I think I'll go with simple option one for now, installing PHP with brew

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 main options:

- Use [DEV container](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/containers) to open and work in the container directly.
- Use an alias, to point to the the DDEV php (the link you posted above). Eg. `~/bin/php`

```
command="ddev . php "$@""
$command
```

Containers keeps things more isolated but can require more configuration if you have multiple projects. Aliases are good, but commands can sometimes run slower.

If you mostly use command-line, you can just open the container in the terminal using `ddev ssh` and run commands there. You wont get all the pretty PHP colors in the main GUI though.

If your on a single project, or all of your projects use the same PHP version, it can be easier to just install it on your host.