# Validate php in vs code with laradock/docker creates new devcontainer

Tags: php, laravel, docker, containers, laradock

I am developing Laravel projects on Mac using Laradock & Docker Desktop.  I use VS Code for editing but everytime I open a project it tells me "Cannot validate since a PHP installation could not be found. Use the setting 'php.validate.executablePath' to configure the PHP executable."

settings.json

```
 {
 "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Light",
 "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
 "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
 "yaml.schemas": {
      "file:///Users/paul/.vscode/extensions/atlassian.atlascode-3.0.9/resources/schemas/pipelines-schema.json": "bitbucket-pipelines.yml"
},
 "php.validate.executablePath": ""
 }
```

I tried to fix the problem by putting that path in...

```
 laradock/php-fpm/php8.2.ini is that the executable php file?

 file:///Users/paul/Sites/laradock/php-fpm/php8.2.ini
```

Then I get that message...

```
 Folder contains a Dev Container configuration file. Reopen folder to develop in a container (learn more).
```

So I re-open in container and now I have 3 containers in Docker Desktop:

```
 laradock with apache2-1 php-fm-1 workspace-1 phpmyadmin-1 mysql-1 docker-indocker-1 redis-1 mailhog-1
 php-mariadb_devcvontainer
 myproject_devcontainer with only db-1 app-1
```

I am completely confused... do I need all that?  I am very happy with laradock but now it's another container...

Comment: 2 solutions: 1) the first one is a bit tricky. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77060944/1294911 . 2) the second one: disable php validation: "php.validate.enable": false

Comment: @UnderDog Thank you for that. I tried the first option which I think worked but now I got this msg when I open my project : "spawn EPERM - Source: PHP Language Features... - open settings" and if I open settings "php.validate.executablePath - backup & sync settings".  What should I do?

Comment: Ok, always try to update your original question with that extra info. It's hard to read error messages in those little comments. Go for option 2: disable PHP validation. Let intellisense handle that one (it's a vsclde extension)