VSCODE setup php executable from my app docker container
Using VSCODE I would like to use the php executable from my current app
My app runs in a container called app based on php latest
in vscode I edit settings.json
  "symfony-vscode.phpExecutablePath": "docker exec -t app php",
  "php.executablePath": "docker exec -t app php",
  "php.validate.executablePath": "docker exec -t app php",

but that does not work I get the following error
Cannot validate since /Users/myuser/Documents/Projects/app/html/docker exec -t app php3 is not a valid php executable. Use the setting 'php.validate.executablePath' to configure the PHP executable.

What is the correct syntax so it does not append /Users/myuser/Documents/Projects/app/html/ before ?

this might be the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66376387/22757599
