# How to configure the visual study code to recognize php with docker?

Tags: php, linux, docker, lamp

I have the following problem with **visual studio code**

[image]

What happens is that I have docker and in the containers is where I have LAMP, the problem is that I get these notices and I can not even use the **heredoc** or **nowdoc** notation for php.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What is your PHP path set to in VS code?

Answer (score 0):

as you can see on this (my own) question some time ago, one mentioned that the volumes work like a one way.

[set PHP path from host to docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44501237/set-php-path-from-host-to-docker-container)

someone answered but i couldnt get it running like he wrote. in my case I simply installed php7 on my localhost and set the path to VSC. maybe this helps you.