# docker php container and local composer issue

Tags: php, docker, windows-10

well I was using wamp-server on windows 10 for a long time and that was fine but now I want to go for docker and use its benefits.
problem is I want to use my docker PHP interpreter on my local machine so according to this question:

[set PHP path from host to docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44501237/set-php-path-from-host-to-docker-container)

I've found a solution to use something like this:

```
docker exec -i php73_fpm php %*
```

in a `php.bat` file, place it in a directory and add it to environment variables and that looks fine.
when i hit `php -v` it shows me the version that i have on docker not locally so that should be fine.
until i tried to use composer. and as soon as i hit `php composer` in a CMD window, it shows an error saying:

```
Could not open input file: C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar
```

this is because i changed `php.exe` path to `php.bat` i assume? and composer is expecting `php.exe` path in environment variables?
how can i force composer to use my docker PHP container not the locally installed one?

EDIT: i will post my docker-compose.yml content here in case that might be needed:

```
version: '3'

networks:
  web_server:
    driver: bridge

services:

  nginx:
    image: nginx
    container_name: nginx_server
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    depends_on:
      - php
      - couchbase
    command: [nginx-debug, '-g', 'daemon off;']
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./docker/nginx/logs:/var/log/nginx
      - ./docker/nginx/sites:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./src:/usr/share/nginx/html
    networks:
      - web_server

  php:
    container_name: php73_fpm
    build:
      context: ./docker/php-fpm
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    working_dir: /usr/share/nginx/html
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: php73-fpm
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    environment:
      - COUCHBASE_HOST=couchbase
      - COUCHBASE_BUCKET_NAME=default
      - COUCHBASE_BUCKET_PASSWORD=
    volumes:
      - ./src:/usr/share/nginx/html
    networks:
      - web_server

  couchbase:
    image: couchbase
    container_name: couchbase
    ports:
        - 8091:8091
        - 8092:8092
        - 8093:8093
    volumes:
      - ./docker/couchbase:/opt/couchbase/var
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    networks:
      - web_server
```

Comment: Is PHP running in a container on itself ?

Comment: You should simply use composer inside your container

Comment: yes it has a separate container. i also have another container for nginx which uses the php container. the problem is with composer and idon't think it needs any web server if you meant that?

Comment: @soju but in that case i cant use it on my host machine directories

Comment: You can mount a folder inside your container

Comment: @soju you mean volume? bc using volume it only makes a symlink between container and host directories but again for running composer i need to do a `docker exec -i php73_fpm composer require something` isnt it?

Comment: thanks guys i've found the solution. with some tricks

Answer (score 0):

First of all this answer is inspired by @soju suggestion about installing composer on the container itself.

well turned out I should have forget my local composer and install it to my container. so i installed it using this line in my php containter's Dockerfile:

```
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

then i should have remove composer directories from environment variables, these directories are:

```
C:\Users\[windows-username-here]\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin
C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar
```

create another composer.bat file and place it somewhere with this content:

```
docker exec -i php73_fpm composer %*
```

add file path to environment variables. and thats it.

now when i use `composer require something` it will send my command to the `php73_fpm` docker container and do the job. but there should be a volume for the folder that i would use in the `docker-compose.yml` file so when it creates the `composer.json` it would place it in that directory on local machine.